# Android Emulator doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, android, sdk, emulation

i've been 24 hours nonstop trying to sort this out with no luck. At first it worked slow, but worked. Then Eclipse started to have errors connecting with the emulator and then the emulator by itself just shows ANDROID_ forever. ( forever as in two hours)
What i've tried in this 24 hours:

-reinstalling eclipse,sdk,jdk.

-deleting .android folder in document and settings.

-waiting 2 hours for the emulator to work by itself.

-downloading the 2.2 image and the 2.2.3 image, also 1.6, none works.

Can you tell me what i've missed?

The emulator just sits forever in the ANDROID_ and occassionaly on the animated ANDROID screen.

My OS is Windows XP SP3.
CPU: AMD64 3600+x2, RAM  1.5 GB

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've got this from DDM

```
05-29 08:06:25.824: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
05-29 08:06:25.824: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
05-29 08:06:25.824: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
05-29 08:06:25.883: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
05-29 08:10:18.927: ERROR/BatteryService(65): usbOnlinePath not found
05-29 08:10:18.927: ERROR/BatteryService(65): batteryVoltagePath not found
05-29 08:10:18.927: ERROR/BatteryService(65): batteryTemperaturePath not found
05-29 08:10:18.927: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(65): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
05-29 08:28:01.794: ERROR/dalvikvm(65): Unable to open trace file '/sdcard/system_process.trace': Permission denied
05-29 08:28:43.294: ERROR/EventHub(65): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
05-29 08:28:43.294: ERROR/EventHub(65): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
05-29 08:28:50.783: ERROR/System(65): Failure starting core service
05-29 08:28:50.783: ERROR/System(65): java.lang.SecurityException
05-29 08:28:50.783: ERROR/System(65):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
05-29 08:28:50.783: ERROR/System(65):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
05-29 08:28:50.783: ERROR/System(65):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
05-29 08:28:50.783: ERROR/System(65):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)
05-29 08:28:51.876: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(65): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
05-29 08:31:41.155: ERROR/vold(26): Cannot start volume '/sdcard' (volume is not bound)
05-29 08:33:44.844: ERROR/vold(26): Framework disconnected
05-29 08:33:45.354: ERROR/installd(31): eof
05-29 08:33:45.354: ERROR/installd(31): failed to read size
05-29 08:33:45.414: ERROR/ActivityThread(119): Failed to find provider info for call_log
```

Is there an alternative to this emulator? I don't have an android device.
I remember testing the sdk 1.0 and it shipped with an interpreter/simulator wich was very fast and simple, did it go away?

Comment: have you delete and create new virtual device? don't run the application from elicpse first. run it from the SDK manager, now can you run the emulator?   if yes, PLEASE DON'T CLOSE THAT EMULATOR. leave it on,  now go to elipse, create a new android project, and when you run configure and point the project to the new device you just created. run from there.try

Comment: Rebooted several times, and i have the same problems running the emulator form the Android SDK and AVD Manager. The closer it gets sometimes is some errors like a problem with pinyin languaje and something like that.

Comment: Any luck with it? Have exactly the same problem.

Comment: No luck, just bought a motorola droid and i kicked that simulator forever.

Comment: It's really funny so see products from google, which are not even supposed to work. Wondering what was these guys who developed emulator were thinking about... they had to start it just once and that's enough to see how crap that is.