# Logcat error - App Crashes on Emulator

Tags: android, sdk, intellij-idea, android-logcat

It was working a while ago, but then an error occurred. I only added the minSDK and TargetSDK in the Android manifest.

Here's the logcat:

```
01-19 23:01:17.054: ERROR/System(51): Failure starting core service
        java.lang.SecurityException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
        at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
        at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
        at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:162)
01-19 23:01:17.094: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(51): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
01-19 23:01:19.553: ERROR/LockPatternKeyguardView(51): Failed to bind to GLS while checking for account
01-19 23:01:24.994: ERROR/ActivityThread(107): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
01-19 23:01:25.034: ERROR/ActivityThread(107): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
01-19 23:01:30.764: ERROR/ApplicationContext(51): Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/wallpaper-hints.xml
01-19 23:01:32.614: ERROR/vold(26): Cannot start volume '/sdcard' (volume is not bound)
01-19 23:01:37.034: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(30): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
01-19 23:01:37.054: ERROR/MediaPlayer(51): Unable to to create media player
01-19 23:01:28.556: ERROR/ActivityThread(104): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
01-19 23:01:30.506: ERROR/ActivityThread(104): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
01-19 23:01:30.627: ERROR/ActivityThread(104): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
```

Comment: You should add more info.
Is your app crashing, or emulator? Please take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166680/android-emulator-doesnt-work-anymore), it seems to be about same problem. And I know it's unanswered, but there are interesting comments there.

Comment: Seems that you use a feature that requires some permissions which must be declared in AndroidManifest.xml. Maybe sdcard access or else?